# haproxy heartbeat with backend based on http post

Tags: haproxy, heartbeat

I want to create a configuration such that the heartbeat between haproxy and the backend is based on HTTP POST.

Does anyone have any idea about this?
I have tried the below configuration, but it only sent the http HEAD to the backend server (I want HTTP POST):

```
backend mlp
    mode http
    balance     roundrobin
    server  mlp1 192.168.12.165:9210 check
    server  mlp2 192.168.12.166:9210 check
```

Thanks for your help.

@Mohsin,
    Thank you so much. I indeed work. 
But I want to specify the request message, seems my configure doesn't work. I appreciate that if you can help too.

[root@LB_vAPP_1 tmp]# more /var/www/index.txt

```html
POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 176.16.0.8:2234\r\nContent-Length: 653\r\n\r\n<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"gb2312\"?>\r\n<svc_init ver=\"3.2.0\">\r\n<hdr ver=\"3.2.0\">\r\n<client>\r\n<id>915948</id>\r\n<pwd>915948</pwd>\r\n<serviceid></serviceid>\r\n</client>\r\n<requestor><id>13969041845</id></requestor>\r\n</hdr>\r\n<slir ver=\"3.2.0\" res_type=\"SYNC\">\r\n<msids><msid enc=\"ASC\" type=\"MSISDN\">00000000000</msid></msids>\r\n<eqop>\r\n<resp_req type=\"LOW_DELAY\"/>\r\n<hor_acc>200</hor_acc>\r\n</eqop>\r\n<geo_info>\r\n<CoordinateReferenceSystem>\r\n<Identifier
>\r\n<code>4326</code>\r\n<codeSpace>EPSG</codeSpace>\r\n<edition>6.1</edition>\r\n</Identifier\r\n</CoordinateReferenceSystem>\r\n</geo_info>\r\n<loc_type type=\"CURRENT_OR_LAST\"/>\r\n<prio type=\"HIGH\"/>\r\n</slir>\r\n</svc_init>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
```

my haproxy.conf file is as bellowing:

```html
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example configuration for a possible web application.  See the
# full configuration options online.
#
#   http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    # to have these messages end up in /var/log/haproxy.log you will
    # need to:
    #
    # 1) configure syslog to accept network log events.  This is done
    #    by adding the '-r' option to the SYSLOGD_OPTIONS in
    #    /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    # 2) configure local2 events to go to the /var/log/haproxy.log
    #   file. A line like the following can be added to
    #   /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    #    local2.*                       /var/log/haproxy.log
    #
    log         127.0.0.1 local7

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    ulimit-n 65536
    daemon
    nbproc 1
    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats
defaults
    mode                    tcp
    retries                 3
    log                     global
    option                  redispatch
#    option                 abortonclose
    retries                 3
    timeout queue           28s
    timeout connect         28s
    timeout client          28s
    timeout server          28s
    timeout check           1s
    maxconn                 32000

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# main frontend which proxys to the backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend  mlp
    mode                tcp
    option                      persist
#    bind                       10.68.97.42:9211 ssl crt /etc/ssl/server.pem
   #bind                        10.68.97.42:9211
    bind                        10.68.97.42:9210
    default_backend             mlp

frontend  supl
    mode                        tcp
    option                      persist
    bind                        10.68.97.42:7275
    default_backend             supl
#-------------
# option1 http check
#------------
backend mlp
    mode http
    balance     roundrobin
 option                      httpchk POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 176.16.0.8:2234\r\nContent-Length: 653\r\n\r\n{<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"gb2312\"?>\r\n<svc_init ver=\"3.2.0\">\r\n<hdr ver=\"3.2.0\">\r\n<client>\r\n<id>915948</id>\r\n<pwd>915948</pwd>\r\n<serviceid></serviceid>\r\n</client>\r\n<requestor><id>13969041845</id></requestor>\r\n</hdr>\r\n<slir ver=\"3.2.0\" res_type=\"SYNC\">\r\n<msids><msid enc=\"ASC\" type=\"MSISDN\">00000000000</msid></msids>\r\n<eqop>\r\n<resp_req type=\"LOW_DELAY\"/>\r\n<hor_acc>200</hor_acc>\r\n</eqop>\r\n<geo_info>\r\n<CoordinateReferenceSystem>\r\n<Identifier>\r\n<code>4326</code>\r\n<codeSpace>EPSG</codeSpace>\r\n<edition>6.1</edition>\r\n</Identifier>\r\n</CoordinateReferenceSystem>\r\n</geo_info>\r\n<loc_type type=\"CURRENT_OR_LAST\"/>\r\n<prio type=\"HIGH\"/>\r\n</slir>\r\n</svc_init>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n}
    http-check                  expect  rstring <result resid=\"4\">UNKNOWN SUBSCRIBER</result>
    server  mlp1 192.168.12.165:9210 check
    server  mlp2 192.168.12.166:9210 check
    #server  mlp2 192.168.12.166:9210 check 


backend supl
    mode tcp
        source  0.0.0.0 usesrc clientip
    balance     roundrobin
    server  supl1 192.168.12.165:7275 check
    server  supl2 192.168.12.166:7275 check
   #server  supl2 192.168.12.166:7275 check
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open haproxy/conf/haproxy.conf file. Goto end of the page, you will see that there is a line 'option httpchk GET /', change GET to POST and you are done.

Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Hi Mohsin, thanks for your answer. But could you please give me more specific advice. which GET in the haproxy.conf should be replaced as POST. Is the following configuration: backend mlp
    mode http
    balance     roundrobin
    option                      httpchk HEAD /index.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n
    http-check                  expect  rstring <result resid=\"4\">UNKNOWN SUBSCRIBER</result>
    server  mlp1 192.168.12.165:9210 check
    server  mlp2 192.168.12.166:9210 check

Comment: Thank you so much, I updated my question, if it's possible, could you please help me to figure it out ? I want to specify my request by the file in the path: /var/www/index.txt . But it doesn't work

Comment: index.txt is not valid. You have to specify a URL of the server which should return a response status of type 2 like 200

Comment: I added the URL like bellowing, but not work still. option                      httpchk POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 176.16.0.8:2234\r\nContent-Length: 653\r\n\r\n{******\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n}

Comment: Please paste the complete content of your haproxy.conf file.

Comment: I have posted it. Thank you so much

Comment: #-------------
# option1 http check
#------------
backend mlp
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk POST /servletPath
    http-check                  expect  rstring <result resid=\"4\">UNKNOWN SUBSCRIBER</result>
    server  mlp1 192.168.12.165:9210 check
    server  mlp2 192.168.12.166:9210 check
    #server  mlp2 192.168.12.166:9210 check 


backend supl
    mode tcp
        source  0.0.0.0 usesrc clientip
    balance     roundrobin
    server  supl1 192.168.12.165:7275 check
    server  supl2 192.168.12.166:7275 check
   #server  supl2 192.168.12.166:7275 check

Comment: Thanks again, i will try this now. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand you correctly. I made the configuration(index.xml is put in the /var/www/, what does your servlet mean? ), but not work still. :backend mlp
    mode http
    balance     roundrobin
    option          httpchk POST /index.html

Comment: In place of index.html write any service URL which would return 200 response

Comment: oh, but I hope it can return some response which can be performed if I send the specified request, no just 200 response . such as:<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svc_result SYSTEM "MLP_SVC_RESULT_320.DTD">
<svc_result ver="3.2.0">
<slia ver="3.2.0">
  <result resid="4">UNKNOWN SUBSCRIBER</result>
  <add_info>Subscriber is unknown or unreachable</add_info>
</slia>
</svc_result>

Answer (score 1):

@Mohsin,
    Thanks for your answer, it gave me the critical clue to resolve this issue.

However, my message is as bellowing, right now it can work as I want(send the specified request and check the specified response). I post it, hopefully, it may help others also. One point is, the content-length is very important.

backend mlp
    mode http
    balance     roundrobin
option httpchk POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent:HAProxy\r\nHost:176.16.0.8:2234\r\nContent-Type:\ text/xml\r\nContent-Length:516\r\n\r\n91594891594813969041845000000000003200

```
http-check                  expect  rstring <result resid=\"4\">UNKNOWN SUBSCRIBER</result>
server  mlp1 192.168.12.165:9210 check
server  mlp2 192.168.12.166:9210 check
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working after a bit of experimenting.

This was my setup

```
HAProxy -> NGINX -> Backend
```

I was sniffing the requests at the NGINX stage with `tcpdump` to see what was actually happening.

In order to change the health check request we have to follow a [hack](https://www.haproxy.com/doc/aloha/7.0/haproxy/healthchecks.html) described in the documentation to change the HTTP version and send headers:

> It is possible to send HTTP headers after the  string by concatenating them using rn and backslashes spaces. This is useful to send Host headers when probing a virtual host

This is the raw http check I want to send:

```
POST ${ENDPOINT} HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/json

{"body": "json"}
```

The big issue here is that HAProxy adds a new header by itself: `Connection: close`, so this is what NGINX gets:

```
POST ${ENDPOINT} HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/json

{"body": "json"}
Connection: close
```

This leads, at least in my case to error 400s due to a malformed request.

The fix is to add a `Content-Length` header:

```
POST ${ENDPOINT} HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 16

{"body": "json"}
Connection: close
```

Since the `Content-Length` should take precedence over the actual length, this forces the last header to be ignored. This is what NGINX passes to the backend:

```
POST ${ENDPOINT} HTTP/1.0
Host: ~^(.+)$
X-Real-IP: ${IP}
X-Forwarded-For: ${IP}
Connection: close
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: application/json

{"body": "json"}
```

This is my final check:

```
option httpchk POST ${ENDPOINT} HTTP/1.0\r\nContent-Type:\ application/json\r\nContent-Length:\ 16\r\n\r\n{\"body\":\"json\"}
```

If it's just JSON you should be ok copying and pasting this and adjusting the content length.
However, I do recommend that you follow the same procedure and sniff the actual health checks, because, with the characters one has to escape in the config file, creating the request properly can be tricky.